# Javascript function is returning unexpected result

Tags: javascript

I have written a good amount of Javascript, primarily using JQuery but I'm stumped on something very simple.

In the following code (also found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6RHF3/)), I simply want to use the boolean return value of the `twoExists()` function in some logic. I have no idea why this behavior is happening, but it works counter intuitively. As in, if I switch the logic I get the result I want.

```
<html>
    <p>One</p>
    <p>Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
    <p>Four</p>
    <strong></strong>
</html>

var myJS = {
    twoExists: function() {
       $("p").each(function() {
          if($(this).text() == "Two") {
              return true;
           }
       });

       return false;
    },
    foo: function() {
        if(myJS.twoExists()) {
            $("strong").text("Found two");
        }
        else {
            $("strong").text("Did not find two");
        }
    }

    bar: function() {
        if(! myJS.twoExists()) {
            $("strong").text("Found two");
        }
        else {
            $("strong").text("Did not find two");
        }
     }
}

myJS.foo(); // result: <strong>Did not find two</strong>
myJS.bar(); // result: <strong>Found two</strong>
```

Comment: "I have written a good amount of Javascript, primarily using Javascript" Um... I don't follow :P

Comment: No matter what you do, you are always going to get false due to this statement: `return false;` So, it's finding two not because you switched but because the opposite of false is true. Try removing the `two` from your options and see..

Comment: +1 for bjb, the quickest way to spot someone who hasn't written JavaScript is when they say jQuery is 'writing JavaScript'

Comment: PW Kad, I did not state jQuery is "writing javascript", I stated that I have **used** jQuery while writing Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return true from the each, you are returning from the callback, not the parent function:

```
   var flag = false;
   $("p").each(function() {
      if($(this).text() == "Two") {
          flag = true;
       }
   });
   return flag;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this might be happening because of how the each loop in jquery returns. `return true` works like a `continue` statement in a normal js loop, I don't think it's going to return from the twoExists function - instead it is going to just jump from the current iteration onto the next one. Maybe try this:

```
twoExists: function() {
   var found = false;
   $("p").each(function() {
      if($(this).text() == "Two") {
          found = true;
       }
   });

   return found;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers mention what is returned is the returned value of the `each` *callback* function not the *twoExists* function. For solving the issue you can also use a simple `for` loop:

```
twoExists: function () {
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p'), 
        l = p.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
        if (p[i].textContent === 'Two') return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using JQuery, you could also take advantage of advanced selectors and save yourself some work:

```
twoExists: function () {
    if ($("p:contains(Two)").length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The other answers provide good insight into your current behavior. Your current `return true;` is returning from the callback to `.each` and JQuery just moves on to the next element, so your `twoExists` function will always return false.